# fix scroll position on button click at certain scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Day 3 of trying to make this work...trying a pure CSS way of doing it (no iScrolls, no niceScroll).  What I want seems simple: scroll a page, when a button is clicked, I want the page to stop scrolling (setting the position to fixed) and keeping the page at that location (not jumping all the way to the top).  I think I might have something wrong with my CSS but here's what I have:

```
        body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        #wrapper{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        header{
            z-index: 2;
            top: 0; left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
        }
```

html

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>Main News</header>
        <ul>link with onclick</ul>
        <ul>link with onclick</ul>
        <ul>link with onclick</ul>
        <ul>link with onclick</ul>
        <ul>link with onclick</ul>
        <ul>link with onclick</ul>
        <ul>link with onclick</ul>
        //a lot more li's with links
    </div>
    <script>
    var x;
        function something(){
            x = $('body').scrollTop();
            $('body').css({
                position: 'fixed'
            });
        });
        function somethingelse(){
            $('body').css({
                position: ''
            });
            $('body').scrollTop(x);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I checked with alerts, the scroll position gets saved in the variable x.  What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT 1:  I also want to add that the links are added dynamically...maybe that's a reason why it keeps scrolling to the top?  No fixed height?

Comment: You are missing `function something()`'s closing curly bracket. Maybe typo?

Comment: @user2025469 Review this example, disable scroll without resetting content position option [link](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/disable_destroy_example.html)

Comment: @FaisalSayed Sorry, that was a typo here, I have the closing brackets in my original code.

Comment: @srk, is there no way to do it with pure css without using external libraries?

Comment: @user2025469 its using simple JQuery, you may want grab the concept how it is done using JQuery > [sample](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/disable_destroy_example.html), that will help you get the solution, or are you looking for something without JQuery?

Comment: @srk I'm developing for mobile so I want to use the smallest library possible.  Right now I'm using Zepto and with other plugins (niceScroll), it needs jQuery.  If it can be done without jQuery, then that would be great.  I'm sure it's possible with CSS because http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_scrolltop_set shows you can click a button and scroll to a position.  I'm not sure why my code isn't working like that!!!

Comment: @user2025469 Why would you want to put it on a fixed position? Have you tried `overflow: hidden;` on the body when you are at a certain point at the page?

Comment: @MarkSmits setting overflow: hidden does not work on a mobile browser.  I tested in Safari.

Comment: @user2025469 I see, how about you do a preventDefault on touchmove? `$('body').on({touchmove: function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` when it should be fixed.

Comment: @MarkSmits Tried that also...problem with this is the div which is brought in to overlay the body needs to remain scrollable...please take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927179/iscroll-a-dynamically-filled-div-only-without-scrolling-main-page-also  It has the complete code of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSmits Quick question...is it possible to preventDefault on a certain element?  For example, if I make not the body scrollable, but the wrapper div with the content, can I disable scrolling of the wrapper by $('#wrapper').on('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault});???  Also, if it's possible, how would I allow scrolling again?

Comment: @user2025469 Can't test that at the moment, but it should work. `$('#wrapper').off()` would turn off the event listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I made a jsFiddle demonstrating how you can 'lock' (or toggle) document scrolling after the user clicks a link. You may be able to create a solution based on this:

```
var ScrollHandler = (function() {
    //Assumes jQuery has initialized
    var hasScrollListener = false;
    var toggleScrollLock = function() {
        if(!hasScrollListener) {
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            $('.freezeScroll').css('color', '#ff0000');
        }
        else { 
            $('body').css('overflow', '');
            $('.freezeScroll').css('color', '#0000ff');
        }
        hasScrollListener = !hasScrollListener;
    }
    //Return a public toggle method
    return {
        toggleScrollLock: toggleScrollLock
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollHandler = new ScrollHandler(),
        links = $('.freezeScroll');
        links.each(function(i, element) {
            $(element).on('click', function(e) { scrollHandler.toggleScrollLock(); });
        });
});
```

Just make sure to modify your list items to include the freezeScroll class:

```
<ul class="freezeScroll">link with onclick</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uQZ8/10/

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it would work but I FINALLY figured out how to implement iScroll on several divs within one page.  What I needed to do is add another div inside the wrapper so not the body is scrolled but the content inside the wrapper.  Thanks for the help, I might use this for something else!